# How to count items found in scripting dictionary?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple set of data that uses a scripting dictionary to find any transaction reference that doesn't have a transaction type. If found, it passes the found values to the column "missing references" in the table "MTypes"
I wanted to stick a counter inside the loop to count how many items were found
and if none, then skip the loop's stage through the scripting dictionary "mKey"
and if any were found then exit the sub after adding the unique values to the table.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Unique_Ref()
Dim ar(), rg As Range
Dim r As Long, CoTy As String, CoTr As String
Dim Wb As Workbook, ShD As Worksheet
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ShD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

'create a scripting dictionary
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'set a dimension range
Dim a As Range: Set a = ShD.Range("F2:F" & ShD.Rows.Count).End(xlDown)   'start point
Dim z As Range: Set z = ShD.Range("G2:G" & ShD.Rows.Count).End(xlDown) 'end point
'set a range from start point to end point
  Set rg = Intersect(ShD.UsedRange, ShD.Range(a, z))
     ar = rg.Value
   For r = 1 To UBound(ar)
  CoTr = Trim(ar(r, 1)) 'Transacton reference
  CoTy = Trim(ar(r, 2)) 'Transaction type
  
   If Len(CStr(CoTy)) = 0 Then 'is blank
        If Not dict.Exists(CoTr) Then 'if not exists already
           dict.Add CoTr, r 'add the value to the dict
           '<........ need to add a counter here
       End If
    End If
   Next r
'loop in the dictionary and pass the value to MTypes table
   Dim mKey As Variant
   For Each mKey In dict.Keys
     ShD.ListObjects("MTypes").ListColumns("Missing references").DataBodyRange.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = mKey
     
  Next mKey
 
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/count-property-dictionary-object

Comment: 1) No need to declare/set a workbook object if you're not going to use it. 2) *"dict.Add CoTr, r 'add the value to the dict"* , did you mean the Transaction Value in column E, the Transaction Type (aka CoTy) or actually the iteration in the array? (from your table called MTypes I'm assuming CoTy, not "r") 3) Wouldn't you need a secundary Dictionary for the ones already added in the MTypes table so you wouldn't add it if it already exists? 4) Wouldn't you add _all_ the references there since they're unique in your example?

Comment: @Notus_Panda No, not need for the value, I'm after the transaction reference (CoTr) that are missing from the table. Also, there is no need for a secondary disct for the table because the transaction type(COty) in the data set comes from the table in the first place. If any transaction reference (Cotr) is missing in the table, that means is not exist in the table. like a vlook up.

Comment: I would say, Ignore the table stage completely because it's an output stage. All needed is a counter within the dict loop to count the references(Cotr) that don't have a type(Coty) and if any are found then how many and add them to the table and if nothing found(all references have types) then jump and don't go to the table stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only changed what was necessary which wasn't much to be honest. Dictionary keeps a count on its own so no need for an extra counter.

```
For r = 1 To UBound(ar)
    CoTr = Trim(ar(r, 1)) 'Transacton reference
    CoTy = Trim(ar(r, 2)) 'Transaction type
      
    If Len(CStr(CoTy)) = 0 Then 'is blank
         If Not dict.Exists(CoTr) Then 'if not exists already
            dict.Add CoTr, r 'add the value to the dict
        End If
    End If
Next r
'loop in the dictionary and pass the value to MTypes table
If dict.Count > 0 Then
    Dim mKey As Variant
    For Each mKey In dict.Keys
        ShD.ListObjects("MTypes").ListColumns("Missing references").DataBodyRange.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = mKey
    Next mKey
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "All references have a type"
End If
```